# Ansible: How to pip install with --upgrade

Tags: pip, ansible

I want to `pip install` with `--upgrade`, using Ansible.

What's the syntax?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
- name: install the package, force upgrade
  pip: 
    name: <your package name>
    state: latest
```

Or with:

```
- name: install the package, force reinstall to the latest version
  pip: 
    name: <your package name>
    state: forcereinstall
```

Comment: Excellent solution, note however that "forcereinstall" will only work for ansible >= 2.1 as http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/pip_module.html

Answer (score 18):

Eventually found the answer here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/a19JEpdXzck

this is the syntax:

```
- name: install the package, force upgrade
  pip: 
    name: <your package name>
    extra_args: --upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using ```shell: > pip install --upgrade pip``` and this is better due I am avoid the ansible-lint rule for shell commands.

Answer (score 15):

If you need upgrade pip for other python version, you can use *executable* parameter:

```
- name: install the package, force upgrade
  pip:
    name: pip
    executable: pip3
    state: latest
```